# Forking with command line arguments

Tags: c, linux, exec, fork, command-line-arguments

I am building a Linux Shell, and my current headache is passing command line arguments to forked/exec'ed programs and system functions.

Currently all input is tokenized on spaces and new lines, in a global variable char * parsed_arguments. For example, the input **dir /usa/folderb** would be tokenized as:

```
parsed_arguments[0] = dir
parsed_arguments[1] = /usa/folderb
```

parsed_arguments tokenizes everything perfectly; My issue now is that i wish to only take a subset of parsed_arguments, which excludes the command/ first argument/path to executable to run in the shell, and store them in a new array, called passed_arguments.

so in the previous example **dir /usa/folderb**

```
parsed_arguments[0] = dir
parsed_arguments[1] = /usa/folderb

passed_arguments[0] = /usa/folderb
passed_arguments[1] = etc....
```

Currently I am not having any luck with this so I'm hoping someone could help me with this. Here is some code of what I have working so far:

How I'm trying to copy arguments:

```
void  command_Line()
{

  int i = 1;
  for(i;parsed_arguments[i]!=NULL;i++)
    printf("%s",parsed_arguments[i]);

}
```

Function to read commands:

```
void readCommand(char newcommand[]){

printf("readCommand: %s\n", newcommand);


//parsed_arguments =  (char* malloc(MAX_ARGS));
//  strcpy(newcommand,inputstring);
  parsed =  parsed_arguments;
  *parsed++ = strtok(newcommand,SEPARATORS);   // tokenize input
    while ((*parsed++ = strtok(NULL,SEPARATORS)))
      //printf("test1\n"); // last entry will be NULL

      //passed_arguments=parsed_arguments[1];

    if(parsed[0]){  
      char *initial_command =parsed[0];

  parsed= parsed_arguments;
  while (*parsed) fprintf(stdout,"%s\n ",*parsed++);
  // free (parsed);
  // free(parsed_arguments);

    }//end of if


  command_Line();

}//end of ReadCommand
```

Forking function:

```
else if(strstr(parsed_arguments[0],"./")!=NULL)
    {
      int pid;
      switch(pid=fork()){
      case -1:
       printf("Fork error, aborting\n");
       abort();
      case 0:
        execv(parsed_arguments[0],passed_arguments);

      }

    }
```

[image]

This is what my shell currently outputs. The first time I run it, it outputs something close to what I want, but every subsequent call breaks the program. In addition, each additional call appends the parsed arguments to the output.

[image]

This is what the original shell produces. Again it's close to what I want, but not quite. I want to omit the command (i.e. "./testline").

Comment: Is there a null pointer at the end of the list of arguments for each command?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler They should all be strings and at the end there should be a null pointer.

Comment: OK; that's one trap avoided.  In the forking code, is this a typo? `execv(parsed_arguments[0], passed_arguments);` where it should probably be `execv(parsed_arguments[0], parsed_arguments);`?  Note that if the `execv()` returns, it fails, but your code goes on to let the failed child continue.  Almost always `exit()` or equivalent after a failed `execv()` or equivalent.  And a message is recommended too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Basically what I'm trying to do is take the subset of parsed_arguments starting at index 1 because it contains the command at index 0. If I use execv(parsed_arguments[0], parsed_arguments); then an example of what would be passed **dir /usa/folderb** and what would be execed would be **dir dir /usa/folderb** because it's going take everything in parsed_arguments when what I want is everything but the command (i.e. "dir").

Comment: On more careful reading of the blurb, I see you have both `parsed_arguments` and `passed_arguments`; those names are dangerously close to each other, and invite confusion and mistakes.  Don't forget that the arguments passed to `execv()` in the vector include the program name at position 0.  If your `passed_arguments` array omits the command name, you're losing the first argument of the command (it is being treated as the command name).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If you take a look at the images I just posted, you can see what kind of problem I'm having.

Comment: Working up some comments into an answer...please study what it means to produce an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  One comment: there are too many global variables and not enough function parameters in this code.

Comment: Did you study the source code of some existing free software shell like `sash` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No I haven't. If I can't resolve this problem then I'll take a look.

Comment: Studying free software source code is really useful for newbies. It teaches you a lot (including things that University is not expected to teach you). So you could study the source code of `sash` even before resolving your problem, it won't harm. Just tell your teacher that you did read the code of `sash`, you probably will make him/her happy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `testline` program is a sensible one to have in your toolbox; I have a similar program that I call `al` (for Argument List) that prints its arguments, one per line.  It doesn't print `argv[0]` though (I know it is called `al`).  You can easily arrange for your `testline` to skip `argv[0]` too.  Note that Unix convention is that `argv[0]` is the name of the program; you should not try to change that (you'll be fighting against the entire system).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    while (*++argv != 0)
        puts(*argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Your function `command_line()` is also reasonable except that it relies unnecessarily on global variables.  Think of global variables as a nasty smell (H<sub>2</sub>S, for example); avoid them when you can.  It should be more like:

```
void command_Line(char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; argv[i] != NULL; i++)
        printf("<<%s>>\n", argv[i]);
}
```

If you're stuck with C89, you'll need to declare `int i;` outside the loop and use just `for (i = 1; ...)` in the loop control.  Note that the printing here separates each argument on a line on its own, and encloses it in marker characters (`<<` and `>>` — change to suit your whims and prejudices).  It would be fine to skip the newline in the loop (maybe use a space instead), and then add a newline after the loop (`putchar('\n');`).  This makes a better, more nearly general purpose debug routine.  (When I write a 'dump' function, I usually use `void dump_argv(FILE *fp, const char *tag, char *argv[])` so that I can print to standard error or standard output, and include a tag string to identify where the dump is written.)

Unfortunately, given the fragmentary nature of your `readCommand()` function, it is not possible to coherently critique it.  The commented out lines are enough to elicit concern, but without the actual code you're running, we can't guess what problems or mistakes you're making.  As shown, it is equivalent to:

```
void readCommand(char newcommand[])
{
    printf("readCommand: %s\n", newcommand);

    parsed = parsed_arguments;
    *parsed++ = strtok(newcommand, SEPARATORS);
    while ((*parsed++ = strtok(NULL, SEPARATORS)) != 0)
    {
        if (parsed[0])
        {
            char *initial_command = parsed[0];
            parsed = parsed_arguments;
            while (*parsed)
                fprintf(stdout, "%s\n ", *parsed++);
        }
    }

    command_Line();
}
```

The variables `parsed` and `parsed_arguments` are both globals and the variable `initial_command` is set but not used (aka 'pointless').  The `if (parsed[0])` test is not safe; you incremented the pointer in the previous line, so it is pointing at indeterminate memory.

Superficially, judging from the screen shots, you are not resetting the `parsed_arguments[]` and/or `passed_arguments[]` arrays correctly on the second use; it might be an index that is not being set to zero.  Without knowing how the data is allocated, it is hard to know what you might be doing wrong.

I recommend closing this question, going back to your system and producing a minimal SSCCE.  It should be under about 100 lines; it need not do the `execv()` (or `fork()`), but should print the commands to be executed using a variant of the `command_Line()` function above.  If this answer prevents you deleting (closing) this question, then edit it with your SSCCE code, and notify me with a comment to this answer so I get to see you've done that.